# Ensime Vim .ensime file not found

Tags: scala, vim, ensime

I'm trying to get Ensime for Vim working, I compiled the project for ensime using sbt 'update' then 'dist', and compiled the c file, but when i try starting ensime in Vim with :Ensime it prints out this error

```
pid : 8492, bufnr : 2
no .ensime file found!
no .ensime file found!
no .ensime file found!
no .ensime file found!
```

and keeps repeating it till I shut vim down.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a .ensime file. Read the [documentation](http://aemon.com/file_dump/ensime_manual.html#tth_sEc3).

Comment: sorry forgot to mention I do have an .ensime file, which looks like this (

:project-package "ensimeTest"

:use-sbt t

)

Comment: Also i have installed Ensime for emacs and it is working fine, its just the vim install that chokes when i start it with :Ensime